# Invalid Request Error trying to integrate stripe payments into my website

Tags: stripe-payments

This is the code from the checkout.js file:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_kEY);
const { productList } = require('../products');

exports.checkoutCtrlFunction = async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const productsFromFrontend = req.body.products;
        console.log(productList);

        function productsToBuy() {
            let products = [];

            productList.forEach( singleProductList => {
                productsFromFrontend.forEach(singleProductFrontend => {
                    if(singleProductList.tag === singleProductFrontend.tag) {
                        products.push({
                            name: singleProductList.name,
                            description: singleProductList.description,
                            images: [singleProductList.image],
                            amount: singleProductList.price * 100,
                            currency: 'usd',
                            quantity: singleProductFrontend.inCart
                        })
                    }
                })
            })

            return products
        }

        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            success_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/checkout/success`,
            cancel_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/cart`,
            shipping_address_collection: {
                allowed_countries: ['US', 'GB']
            },
            line_items: productsToBuy()

        });

        res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            session: session
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The error is:

You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items.images` in this API version. Please use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`.

Don't understand why I keep getting this error I think i provided the necessary information, I assume something isn't formatted correctly, but im not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your Stripe account is on the latest version of the Stripe API (2022-08-01), and this code was used and/or written by someone who was on an earlier version.

The latest version of the Stripe API removed the parameters `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, etc. This is listed as one of the breaking changes with version 2022-08-01: https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01

Here's the API reference for creating Checkout Sessions using `line_items.price` and `line_items.price_data`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items.

If you'd like to test this code as is, you can specify an older Stripe version  with the `apiVersion` option: https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning?lang=node